# Handling an input stream one line at a time - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I've got an input stream containing 200k+ JSON objects. Each object is on a new line. I'm unsure as to how I would go about parsing these objects in a line-by-line fashion.

Comment: Do you need to, or do you just need to use a streaming parser?

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you have a stream of bytes, containing multiple JSONs separated by a new line?

Comment: You need a streaming parser

Comment: Yes. That's correct CouchDeveloper. It is the first time I've had to deal with data in this way, so I'm not entirely how to interact with the data. A streaming parser sounds like it'd be useful, I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case you have a content type which consists of multiple JSONs, you would purposefully use an *appropriate* parser which can handle that kind of task.

The *usual* JSON parser (NSJSONSerialization) is not able to parse this kind of document, since strictly it can only parse *one* JSON document.

A streaming parser may also not be the kind of parser which deals with those sorts of documents. It must be specifically designed to handle "multiple JSON" documents.

You may take a look at [JPJson](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/JPJson). This JSON parser *can* handle multiple JSON documents within one stream of bytes. It's also fast and works with a constant memory footprint.

I'm the author of this library, it might be worth a try.